# How do I reveal my button only when on a specific component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I want to show the Logout button on the same row of the title but only when the user has made it to Home component.

In other words, I don't want to show the logout button at all times, especially when the user's at the login screen. I want it to show on the same row of the title only when they've logged in successfully and they're in Home

How would I achieve this?  My head hurts from trying to make this work :(

Below's what I've tried so far, among other things.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import classes from './Title.css';
import LogoutButton from '../../containers/LogoutButton/LogoutButton';
import Home from '../../components/Home/Home';

class Title extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            show: false,
            showLogoutButton: true
        };
    }

    showButton() {
        this.setState({show: true});

        if(this.state.show) {
            return <LogoutButton/>;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                { this.state.showLogoutButton ? this.showButton : null }
                <h1 className={classes.Title}>Pick Ups</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Title;
```

Comment: quite a few issues here.. the main thing that for sure is wrong is that `this.showButton` is a function, but inside your render method you're not actually calling it. missing `()`

Comment: @azium If I put the `()` I get an error on my browser that says `Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

Comment: Where are you using this `Title` component? Why are you importing `Home` inside the `Title` component? If you have another component beside `Home`, maybe called `Login` and you use `Title` within both of those components, you would want to use a prop like this `<Title showLogoutButton={true/false} />` and then in your `Title` component reference `this.props.showLogoutButton` instead of `this.state.showLogoutButton`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below. You don't need to deal with function and modifying states.

You can simply do like below

```
import classes from './Title.css';
import LogoutButton from '../../containers/LogoutButton/LogoutButton';
import Home from '../../components/Home/Home';

class Title extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showLogoutButton: this.props.authenticated
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { showLogoutButton } = this.state;
        return(
            <div className="row" style={{"display" :"flex"}}>
                { showLogoutButton && <LogoutButton/>}
                <h1 className={classes.Title}>Pick Ups</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Title;
```

Note: When you modify state using setState the state value will be updated only after render so you can't directly check immediately modifying the value.

Comment: hmm ok.  but how would I used `authenticated ` prop (from `<Title/>` component) in `<Home/>` component?  Upon using `<Title/>` component and setting `authenticated = true ` (or false) inside `<Home/>` component, it's showing my title twice.

Comment: Not sure how you are authenticating user. From your homecomponent send a Boolean prop authenticated true to Title component when user is logged I successfully else send false. Then everything will work as expected